# Is there a way to use a variable in a wscript shell run function?

Tags: vbscript, wscript.shell

For some reason my code brings up an error stating that

```
Script: startup.vbs

Line: 10

Char: 2

Error: Invalid procedure call or argument

Code: 800A0005
```

Source: Microsoft VBScript Runtime Error

My code that I used:
***[THE CODE](http://txt.do/tavoc)***

Comment: The code block would not work so I put it in an external link and the error id was counted as code to stackoverflow D:<.

Comment: My browser block's access to tx.do. You can past the code as is, and if formatting doesn't work for you someone else will do it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

With vague details... This is how I've used variables with Wscript Shell Run.

```
Sub RunCommand(command)
    cmd = "cmd /c "" & command & """"
    set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")
    shell.run cmd
    set shell=nothing
End Sub
```

I would definitely say the code you provided has quite a few deficiencies in how it works and misuse of Subroutines versus Functions. Functions return something and subroutines do not.

iecho is regurgitating an entire string "vbyes parent:child true" and not truely the "child" value you're desiring since it doesn't operate like that. There's other things but you asked how to use variables for functions. There ya go. :)

Comment: What code kind is it 

cmd = "cmd /c "" & command & """"""
Do I use batch code for the cmd var or vbscript?

Comment: Why so many quotes after? Should be `""""` shouldn’t it?

Comment: @thatjsonkid - as user692942 point out, it should be `""""` but that executes command in command prompt. It was an example of arguments / variables. CMD just also happens to be a the executable to run things in command prompt.